# How to dynamically add a textarea with the same style as the other Textareas in the same div. Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to add a textarea with a button click. This textarea should have the same style as the others in the same div. I want to add the class "note" to it which I created in my CSS file.

**my-nav.component.html**

```html
<div class="square" id="notes" ng-repeat="textArea in textAreas">
  <textarea autofocus class ="note" style="font-size: 15px" placeholder="Apple"></textarea>
</div>
```

**my-nav.component.ts**

```js
 onClickAdd() {
   const div = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
   div.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";
   div.classList.add("note");
   document.getElementById("notes").appendChild(div);
 }
```

**CSS**

```css
.note {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #d0a090 1px, #d0a090 1px), linear-gradient(#fdf8c8, #fdf8c8 23px, #ccd 23px, #ccd 24px, #fdf8c8 24px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #d0a090 1px, #d0a090 1px), linear-gradient(#fdf8c8, #fdf8c8 23px, #ccd 23px, #ccd 24px, #fdf8c8 24px);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #d0a090 1px, #d0a090 1px), linear-gradient(#fdf8c8, #fdf8c8 23px, #ccd 23px, #ccd 24px, #fdf8c8 24px);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #d0a090 1px, #d0a090 1px), linear-gradient(#fdf8c8, #fdf8c8 23px, #ccd 23px, #ccd 24px, #fdf8c8 24px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #d0a090 1px, #d0a090 1px), linear-gradient(#fdf8c8, #fdf8c8 23px, #ccd 23px, #ccd 24px, #fdf8c8 24px);
  background-size: 2px 100%, 100% 24px;
  background-position: 40px top, left 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  background-attachment: local;    
}
```

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Current situation]

Comment: That’s not remotely how angular works, you’d simply loop there. Maybe have a read at a angular starting guide first, it will surely help you.

Comment: I already tried it with a loop.

Comment: onclick of which button do you want thus to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-repeat is for AngularJS. For Angular you will want to use *ngFor and it would look like the following:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-textarea

```
<button (click)="addTextArea()" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"> Add Text Area</button>
<div class="square" id="notes" *ngFor="let textArea of textAreas">
    <textarea autofocus class="note" [(ngModel)]="textArea.value" style="font-size: 15px"  placeholder="Apple"></textarea>
</div>

<h5>Text Area Values</h5>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let textArea of textAreas">{{textArea | json}}</li>
</ul>
```

And Component

```
  textAreas: { value: string }[] = [{value: ''}];

  addTextArea() {
    const textArea = { value: '' };
    this.textAreas.push(textArea)
  }
```

I added an example of passing the value as a parameter as well.

Comment: Fixed my example and added a stackblitz